# Firebase dataSnapshot.value is now Object? It was Map

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Help. My flutter class works perfectly last year, but now, DataSnapShot value property returns Object? as oppose to Map.

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Users {
  String id;
  String email;
  String name;
      
  Users({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.name,
  });

  factory Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) => Users(
        id: dataSnapshot.key!,
        email: dataSnapshot.value["email"],
        name: dataSnapshot.value["name"],
      );
}
```

I want to read data from my firebase realtime database referenced, any help will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who may find this useful, changing the dependence version, but I want to use the latest Firebase_database dependence, I really need a support on how to use the latest version.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: 1.10.0
  firebase_database: 8.1.0
```